# Convert Published<String>.Publisher' to specified type 'String' / SwiftUI / Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, type-conversion

I want to convert Published.Publisher' to specified type 'String'. I use @ObservedObject var textFieldManager = TextFieldManager() Because I have a TextField an I want to use a character limit there.
And now I want to convert it to a String to use the userInput.
It is not working..

```
                        
let myStringUserInput: String = textFieldManager.$userInput

class TextFieldManager: ObservableObject {
    
    let characterLimit = 4
    
 
    @Published var userInput = "" {
        
            didSet {
                if userInput.count > characterLimit {
                    userInput = String(userInput.prefix(characterLimit - 1))
                }
            }
        }
    
}
```

Comment: What is TextFieldManager and how is userInput defined? Doesn't `textFieldManager.userInput` work?

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: class TextFieldManager: ObservableObject {
    
    let characterLimit = 4
    
 
    @Published var userInput = "" {
        
            didSet {
                if userInput.count > characterLimit {
                    userInput = String(userInput.prefix(characterLimit - 1))
                }
            }
        }
    
}

Comment: Comments is not good place to provide code - just edit your question and add your code there.

Comment: Did it. Look at my edit :)

Answer (score 0):

textFieldManager.$userInput
"$" was my mistake. Should be without it.
Thanks anyways.